# Automation: Application trigger to execute another application

Tags: automation, scripting, autohotkey

I suppose some backstory should help better understand my situation. I had relied on Intel Control Panel's profiler to switch graphics profiles when game.exe would run. It had an application trigger option that would automatically detect the exe when added to its list of exes and it would activate a graphics profile. It would also automatically revert to the previous profile when the game.exe exited. After a recent driver update, the application trigger feature stopped working. As an alternative I setup two bat files that use commandline arguments to the Control Panel exe to trigger the profiles manually. I was looking to automate this process and I've made some progress in AHK but something is wrong. I'm also open to using something else besides AHK if it does what its supposed to. I just thought AHK was a good start for these sorta things.
So far I've got:

```
#Persistent

Profile1:
Process, Wait, notepad.exe
{
    Run C:\ProfileChange.bat
    Process, WaitClose, notepad.exe
    {
        Run C:\RevertProfile.bat
        Goto Profile1
    }
}
```

This code works but now I need a way to store the process names and check against every name in that list so the code becomes flexible and resuable.

Basically I'm looking to:

1. Check if game exe is executed and in list,
2. if so, run gamingprofile.bat
3. When game exits,
4. run removegamingprofile.bat

Rinse repeat, (Go back to 1)

Ideally, it would be great if all the exes that follow this pattern could be placed in a array of sorts and the code becomes more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

My solution briefly explained:

I created an array in which I placed the names of the exes that I want to have trigger the execution (for this example I used notepad and cmd, which comes preinstalled on all Windows computers. I for-looped through the array, each time, testing within the span of 1 second to see if there exists an instance of the current program from the current index of the array. If there was not, then move on to the next program in the array. However, if that program does exist, then run `C:\ProfileChange.bat` and have the program wait until it exits. After it exits, run `C:\RevertProfile.bat`. If my explanation was hard to follow, the code is probably easier to understand.

```
#Persistent

exes := ["notepad.exe", "cmd.exe"]
Loop{
for index, element in exes 
{
    Process, Wait, %element%, 1
    NewPID := ErrorLevel
        if not NewPID
    {
        continue
    }
    {
        Run C:\ProfileChange.bat
        Process, WaitClose, %element%
        {
            Run C:\RevertProfile.bat
        }
    }
}
}
```

Note: You can probably decrease the One-second time to check for an instance of a program from `Process, Wait, %element%, 1` to a decimal such as `Process, Wait, %element%, .01` if you plan on using it for a lot of different possible trigger programs, but when I tested it with .01 seconds of delay, I noticed that my computer was running a bit laggier. You can probably fine-tune it on your end to find to optimize it for your particular computer.